# How to use vlc Internet Playlist selections besides Icecast?

Tags: vlc-media-player

My vlc Internet Playlist shows Free Music Charts, iCast Stream Directory, Icecast Radio Directory, Jamendo Selections, Channels.com, and Podcasts. The only one of these that gives me anything to choose is Icecast Radio Directory (which works, perfectly). How do I use the others?

Comment: [I listen to music from Jamendo using VLC](http://support.moonpoint.com/software/audio_video/VLC/Jamendo/) on a Microsoft Windows system. Sometimes when I've clicked on Jamendo, I've had to wait a minute before the full list of music categories has appeared and there was at least one occasion where Jamendo was the only one showing me anything.

Comment: Yes, after reading a post on ghacks, I waited a longer time and Jamendo finally populated the playlist. Some of the others still did not. The funny thing to me is that there is a "waiting" spinner graphic, but it disappears long before the playlist actually populates.